# Spring Boot, Jolokia Remote Access returns No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: cross-domain, spring-boot, jolokia

I setup jolokia with jmx on my spring boot application, so I can get jmx information over HTTP.

However I can't get the data by javascript ajax with the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."

I want to make jolokia endpoint return 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header to allow any origin or at lease return the header with allowed origin I specified on jolokia-access.xml, but I don't get the header on response and I'm not sure what I missed

The monitoring javascript I'm running is not on same server which has my spring boot application, since I want to make the script run remotely.

Below is my spring boot application setup.

application.properties and jolokia-access.xml both are in classpath, so I can see the change I made for management.port on application.properties and remote post access restriction on jolokia-access.xml are applied

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        :
```

**application.properties**

```
management.port=8888

endpoints.jolokia.path=/jolokia
endpoints.jolokia.enabled=true

endpoints.jmx.enabled=true

endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=*
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=*
endpoints.cors.allowed-headers=*
```

**jolokia-access.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<restrict>
    <remote>
        <host>127.0.0.1</host>
        <host>localhost</host>
    </remote>

    <http>
        <method>post</method>
        <method>get</method>
    </http>

    <commands>
        <command>read</command>
        <command>list</command>
        <command>version</command>
    </commands>

    <cors>
        <allow-origin>http://localhost:*</allow-origin>
        <allow-origin>http://127.0.0.1:*</allow-origin>
    </cors>
</restrict>
```

When I hit the jolokia endpoint by curl, I can have jmx data on response as json like below

```
$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8888/jolokia -d '{
    "type":"read",
    "mbean":"org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=healthEndpoint",
    "attribute":"Data"
}'
{"request":{"mbean":"org.springframework.boot:name=healthEndpoint,type=Endpoint","attribute":"Data","type":"read"},
"value":{"diskSpace":{"threshold":10485760,"free":204441415680,"status":"UP"},"db":{"database":"H2","hello":1,"status":"UP"},"status":"UP"},
"timestamp":1433908260,"status":200}


$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8888/jolokia -d '{
    "type":"read", 
    "mbean":"java.lang:type=Memory", 
    "attribute":"HeapMemoryUsage", 
    "path":"used"
}'
{"request":{"path":"used","mbean":"java.lang:type=Memory","attribute":"HeapMemoryUsage","type":"read"},
"value":69036712,"timestamp":1434075946,"status":200}
```

However below javascipt failed since resposne from jolokia endpoint doesn't have Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.
Even if I setup 'endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=*' properties, but I don't see the header on the response

**Monitoring javascript**

```
var j4p = new Jolokia({url: "http://127.0.0.1:8888/jolokia", fetchInterval: 1000});

var context = cubism.context()
    .serverDelay(0)
    .clientDelay(0)
    .step(1000)
    .size(594);
var jolokia = context.jolokia(j4p);

var memory = jolokia.metric(
    function (resp1, resp2) {
        return Number(resp1.value) / Number(resp2.value);
    },
    {type:"read", mbean:"java.lang:type=Memory", attribute:"HeapMemoryUsage", path:"used"},
    {type:"read", mbean:"java.lang:type=Memory", attribute:"HeapMemoryUsage", path:"max"}, "Heap-Memory"
);
```

**Request header the javascript sent**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:127.0.0.1:8888
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8080
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8080/monitor/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
```

**Response header the javascript received**

```
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 12 Jun 2015 02:27:17 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Jetty(9.2.10.v20150310)
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

As you see above, there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header at all.

Comment: The `endpoints.cors.*` properties are new in Spring Boot 1.3.0 so they won't work with 1.2.x

Comment: Isn't there any way to enable cross origin for jolokia on spring boot in version 1.2.4 which is latest release version? If there is no way, then we cannot use javascript to access jolokia.  I checked enabling cross origin by introducing filter for spring mvc (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ ) and tried, but I found that it is just enabling cross origin only on my spring boot app, not on jolokia

Comment: I tested this again with updating my project to Spring Boot version 1.3.0.RELEASE and checked this issue has been resolved when I setup below properties on application.properties file.                endpoints.cors.allowed-headers=*  endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=*
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=*

Answer (score 0):

By default, Jolokia allows any cross origin access. So there is no need for a `jolokia-access.xml` at all.

On the other hand, I think your pattern should work. But please raise an issue on GitHub so that we can continue there to fix this.

Comment: I loaded up my code onto GitHub ( https://github.com/wsapiens/jolokia ) so people can look into. please let me know if that is not good enough and I should take more action

Comment: I create issue on GitHub ( https://github.com/rhuss/jolokia/issues/202 ) for this issue.